# Apply Site Policy to Multiple Site Collections with PnP Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

Over time, a lot of SPO site collections have accumulated in my tenant. Therefore, I want to use Site Collection Feature called Site Policy to automatically close and delete sites after a defined period of time.

To do that, I headed over to ContentTypeHub and created a site policy that closes a site after 6 months of its creation date, and then deletes that site after 12 months of its closure date.

When I want to apply this policy using GUI, it works well. Also, when I try to apply it using PnP PowerShell, it works. However, it is only applied at one site per-time. As mentioned, I'm dealing with a large number of sites and want to apply this policy to either all of them, or to a 10, 20, 50 of them at a time.

I used the following PnP PowerShell script to apply it to apply the policy on, at the beginning, 2 sites only:

[image]

2 sites, that is their URLs, are stored in a .csv file called SiteCollections.csv. This is how it looks:

[image]

When I run the script from above, I don't get any errors. This is my output:

[image]

It seems that all works fine, but when I head over to the GUI to check it, policies are not applied:

[image]

Is there something that I'm missing?
Any help, suggestion or tip is more than welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: Does it work if you connect to a site manually and apply the policy?

Comment: Yes, it works if I connect to a single site and run the command. When I try to do it for multiple sites (2 in this occasion), I experience this outcome.

Comment: I wonder if the connections is the problem - try to bind the connection in the loop to a variable and use the switch -returnConnection on the cmd connect-pnp. Then on set-pnpsitepolicy, use the -connection switch and pass the connection.

$CurrConnection = Connect-PnPOnline -Site $site.SiteUrl -Interactive -ReturnConnection

And then Set-PnPSitePolicy -Name $PolicyName -Connection $CurrConnection

Comment: And don't forget to close the connection when done on each site inside the loop.

Comment: Just tried out your suggestion, unfortunately didn't work. I get the same output as last time, but when I check the sites to see if the policy is applied, it's not.

Comment: I'd try application authentication vs interactive authentication

Comment: Hi @VladKarasovSharePointMCSE, thanks for your suggestion. Just to be clear, by application authentication, did you mean to register an app on Azure and use it for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, exactly. With application you'd be able to authenticate to every site unattended - using secret or certificate.
https://vladilen.com/sharepoint/access-spo-site-programmatically/